# Dafny loop invariant not mantained by th loop

Tags: dafny

i have to create the pre and pos conditions for the method insert of a heap class, the heap as to be a minHeap and has to be completed, my invariant has an error that says: "this loop invariant might not be maintained by the loop."

```
    class Heap {
var size: nat
var heap: array<int>
method insert (x: int)
    modifies heap
    requires 0 < size < heap.Length - 1
    requires minHeap(heap, size)
    requires x > 0
    requires isComplete(heap, size)
    ensures minHeap(heap, size + 1)
    ensures isComplete(heap, size + 1)
    ensures exists i :: 0 < i < size + 1 && x == heap[i]
    {
        // Insert the new item at the end of the array 
        var pos:= size + 1;
        // Percolate up
        while pos > 1 && x < heap[pos/2]
        invariant 1 <= pos < heap.Length
        invariant forall i :: pos < i <= size + 1 ==> heap[i] < heap[i/2]
        {

            heap[pos] := heap[pos/2];
            pos:= pos/2;
        }
        heap[pos] := x;
    }

    predicate minHeap(h: array<int>, index: nat)
    reads h
    requires 0 < index < h.Length 
    {
        forall i :: 1 < i < index ==> h[i/2] < h[i]
    } 

    predicate isComplete(h: array<int>, index: nat)
    reads h 
    requires 0 < index < h.Length
    {
        forall i :: 1 <= i <= index ==> h[i] > 0
    }
  }
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the loop invariant holds at the beginning of an iteration when `pos` is `100`. Then you know

```
forall i :: 100 < i <= size+1 ==> heap[i] < heap[i/2]
```

at the beginning of the loop iteration. That is, you know something about `heap[i]` for all `i` greater than `100` (up to `size+1`). The loop iteration now sets `heap[100]` to the value of `heap[50]`, and sets `pos` to `50`. To prove that the loop invariant is maintained, you would now need to show:

```
forall i :: 50 < i <= size+1 ==> heap[i] < heap[i/2]
```

But this condition certainly does not hold. One problem is that it does not hold for `i == 100`, because `heap[100]` is *equal* to `heap[50]`, not strictly less than `heap[50]` as your loop invariant states. The other problem is that you have no information about the values of `heap[51], ..., heap[99]`, and your loop invariant says that you intend each of these to satisfy `heap[i] < heap[i/2]` as well.

So, you need to rethink either your program or the invariant, or both.